# How to change gd ratings stars colors

Tags: css, wordpress

In gd star ratings plugin, they take a css sprite image for displaying the status of the stars and adjust its width to show how many stars an item is rated by.

They use the image "gd-star-rating/stars/oxygen/stars20.png" for example in the background.

For example, I have 3 stars so it takes 60px width.

```
.starsbar.gdsr-size-20 a.s3 {
width: 60px;
}
```

and the global code is:

```
.gdsr-oxygen .starsbar.gdsr-size-20 a:hover {
background: url('../stars/oxygen/stars20.png') repeat-x 0px -20px !important;
}
```

My question is, how do I change the colors of these stars using my custom image? I want to have

red  - 1 stars
yellow - 2 stars

and gradually, green for 5 stars.

Is it something achievable?

Answer (score 0):

You could add or change the class on the star, and apply styles based on that using greater specificity:

```
.gdsr-oxygen .starsbar.gdsr-size-20 a {
  background: url('../stars/oxygen/stars20.png') repeat-x 0px -20px !important;
}

.gdsr-oxygen .starsbar.gdsr-size-20 a.red {
  background: url('../stars/oxygen/stars20_red.png') repeat-x 0px -20px !important;
}
```

You could also extend the original sprite and change its position to show the red or yellow stars:

```
.gdsr-oxygen .starsbar.gdsr-size-20 a.red {
  background-position: 0px -40px !important;
}
```